# how to put more than one filter in a java table

Tags: java, swing, filter

The method that I am using only works on a single piece of data, but I need more data to be filtered.

To filter the data, I'm using a text box.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    textFecha.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            //super.keyReleased(e); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + textFecha.getText(), 0));
            //trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("?i"+txtfiltro.getText(), 1));
        }
        
        
        //public void KeyReleased(final KeyEvent evt) {}
    });
    
    trs = new TableRowSorter(dtm);
    table.setRowSorter(trs);
    
    List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    int columnIndexToSort = 2;
    
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    trs.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    trs.sort();
}
```

Comment: In other words, the text of your question doesn't really tell us what is going on, and the example code doesn't really show anything either.  With this as is, it's unlikely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Use the `RowFilter.andFilter(...)` method. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450644/jtable-row-filtering-based-on-values-of-two-different-columns/17451538#17451538